# htaccess: redirect to parts of the url if it contains certain string

Tags: regex, .htaccess

In the past there must have been an error in the generation of links all around my website.

Now I want to redirect all the malformed links that are still used by people and which lead to 404 to the correct page.

An example of a wrong url:

```
http://www.example.com/foo/bar/www.example.com/bar/foo
```

The correct url would be `/bar/foo`, so I have to check if the url contains the name of my website: www.example.com and if it does, it should redirect to the rest `/bar/foo`.

Static example: If I would write all of them individually instead of using regex

```
RewriteRule ^foo/bar/www.example.com/bar/foo/ /bar/foo [R=301,L]
```

I have spent quite some time of here reading about regex etc. but I didn't find a solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^.+/.+/www.example.com/(.+)/?$ /$1 [R=301,L]` ?

Comment: @starkeen: Could you explain your approach pls. What does `/$1` exactly do? How could that be string after `www.example.com`. Thanks

Comment: Dom1337  please read the official mod rewrite guide . 
 https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html  .

Comment: Okay now it makes total sense. Thank you! For others interested: `RewriteRule backreferences: These are backreferences of the form $N (0 <= N <= 9). $1 to $9 provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions. $0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.`